# PHP include file from root when using sub domain

Tags: php, html

I have a website with a subdomain *(my.domain.com)*

my main website uses

```
include 'directory/page.php';
```

and on the subdomain i want to be able to include the same file, i have tried:

```
include realpath(dirname($_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]) . '/../..').'/directory/page.php';
```

but i get an error saying the file cannot be found.

My directory structure looks like:

```
www.domain.com - /home/username/public_html
my.domain.com - /home/username/public_html/my
```

how can i include a file in the `public_html` directory in the `my.` subdomain?

Comment: use include('http://www.domain.com/page.php'); in your subdomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include dirname(__DIR__).'/directory/page.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://developer.hyvor.com/php/including-files-in-root-with-subdomain.php) to learn more

Simply,

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/../directory/page.php';
```